# Apple Enterprise Developer Program for in-house Development Approval Process

Tags: ios4

My question is that let's say I develop an iPhone app using the Apple Enterprise Developer Program for in-house distribution. After the app is complete do I have to send the app for approval process to Apple or not?

Also, If I distribute the app in-house how many devices can it be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, App store approval is only for applications to be distributed through the store. Internal distribution on an enterprise license doesn't require it at all.

Comment: Thanks! Also, do you know how many devices an install an in-house app.